# error running asp.net 1.1 and 2.0 together

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2003

So here is the error that I am trying to help a friend with (I don't think I would have tried this).   He has a legacy Asp.net 1.1 application.  He has already added some ASP.NET 2.0 features to his application.  His app is running on a Windows 2003 server.  He has the main application running in a 1.1 app pool.  In one of the sub folders is where all of the .Net 2.0 features are living so he has added a second web application to IIS that points to the sub folder and put this app in a 2.0 app pool.  His application runs well most of the time but intermittently users are getting a "White screen" and the whole application is going down(He is 95% sure that it is the 1.1 app pool that is going down).  How can he fix his problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in the Application and System event logs on the server.  You should the W3SVC crashing and a reason why.  Double and triple-check that no app pool contains applications which run both runtimes.  Also, you can only run ASP.NET 1.1 and 2.0 in parallel on IIS if it's running in 32-bit mode, because .NET 1.1 is 32-bit only.